# Value Suggestion for SAP Dynpro input field

Tags: abap, dynpro

I need to show suggestions when someone types something into my input field.
It's a field for a transport request. So if someone starts to type something in it shows at the moment last entered entries but it should make suggestions what to type in (like it happens for example in transaciton VA02 ). I want a dropdown of a selection of the table E070 where I can see the request and the short text.

I did use google but i just found this, but i've got a normal dynpro and no WebDynpro.

Comment: ...any reason for the last edit that re-introduced spelling and formatting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is [Enhanced Search](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/03/10/spotlight-on-the-enhanced-search-f4-help/). You can provide your own enhanced search implementation by [creating a search help](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/cf/21ee5f446011d189700000e8322d00/frameset.htm) and activating the **proposal search** feature. Note that the enhanced search can be turned off in the GUI Settings, though - and many users and organizations do so because it tends to be irritating for long-time experienced users.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I'll try.